# How to get the URI of a ROS node in Python?

Tags: rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to find machines that publish a certain type of message. Therefore I'm inspecting the list of rosnodes `rosnode.rosnode_listnodes()` and would like to **get the IP address of the corresponding machines running a specific node**.

There is a method `rosnode.lookup_uri(...)`, but I have no idea how to use it. I also looked into the `rospy`, `rosgraph`, `names` and `network` modules - so far without success. Among other information,`rosnode.rosnode_info(node_name)` prints the URI. But it might be a rather expensive method and, unfortunately, it returns `None`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247262/how-to-get-the-uri-of-a-ros-node-in-python?/) by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 268 on 2016-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
>>> import rosgraph
>>> master = rosgraph.Master('/mynode')
>>> master.lookupNode("node_name')
```

This worked for me, but not sure if it's safe to deal with ros master directly this way.

---

Originally posted by [huanxiner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28265/huanxiner/) with karma: 271 on 2016-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-05**:
Alternatively, you could use the [Master API](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Master_API) directly.

**Comment by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) on 2016-11-07**:
Great, thanks! Apparently, you can even get the `master` via `rosgraph.Master('')`. It's definitely the answer I was looking for. :)